# Using POST method to authorize users ::Angular2&TypeScript

Tags: javascript, authentication, angular, post, typescript

An user while logging into my app is autorized from server. It works like this:

- user writes login and password into separate inputs
- when he clicks login button, a http post request is being send on adress: 
  `http://localhost/api/auth/${this.username}/${this.password}`
- the response from server is boolean. If login and passwords are fine, response is **true**, if not - **false**.

This is my request:

```
this.http.post(`http://localhost/api/auth/${this.username}/${this.password}`, cred, {
  headers: headers
})
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
        data => this.response = data,
        err => console.log('error'),
        () => console.log('Authentication Complete')
    );
```

My problem is I dont know what is that `cred` variable just right after the link. Do I need these `headers`? Is it even supposed to work?

I will upvote every answer. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT** Correct login and password are admin/admin.

So if users writes admin/admin it will return `true`.

Comment: uhmm, just a comment: Should you perhaps re-think to send username and password in url...

Comment: @AJT_82 It's just a temporary solution

Comment: Oh okay, good! :)

Comment: @AJT_82 But is it correct? The code... Or should I do it by `get`?

Comment: @AJT_82 Thank you my dear friend

Comment: I messed up myself with post and get here :D Well, take a look at this in the meantime https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html What is your backend, how does the receiving end of this request look like? Could you add that to your question? I'm not even sure what that `cred` is for, that´s why I'm asking about the backend :)

Comment: @AJT_82 I don't know to be honest what is `creds` variable. It was just in angular2 docs. And the response from server is just true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [TOH-Http](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) it's a good tutorial!

Yes, since you are only requesting a url, you don't need to use post. Post is for when you send body with your request.

As we discussed in comments, this is a working solution:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost/api/auth/${this.username}/${this.password}') 
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(d => console.log(d))
```

I would though suggest you do the mapping in the service (I suppose you are doing this request in the service) and do the `.subscribe` in your component that calls this http-request. In your case, since you are receiving just `false` or `true` you could do it like this:

```
    return this.http.get('http://localhost/api/auth/${this.username}/${this.password}')
        .map((res: Response) => {
            let resp = res.json();
            if (resp == true) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
       .catch(... 
}
```

And in your method you call for http-request `.subscribe` like so:

```
.subscribe(res => {
    if(res == true) {
        // do something...
    } else {
        // do something else...
    }
})
```

And as mentioned, in future, do not send your username and password in url! ;)

Comment: Yes, it's correct, I got messed up with get and post myself ;) You are just requesting the url, therefore you don't need to use post. Tell me if it works, and I'll edit my post a bit (set better subscribe... etc)

Comment: If I write admin/admin it returns true. If i write something else, it returns false.

Comment: So you tried using my get method, and it worked? I'm a bit unsure since you said that if you "write admin/admin, it works".

Comment: Yes if i write admin/admin it returns true and if i write something else it returns false, so i think it works now.

Comment: Yes, then it works, the error 500 is what should be displayed if the credentials are correct. I'll ellaborate my answer a bit better, with handling the true or false statement etc. So if you then kindly would accept my answer, that would be great!

Comment: ThanX for all :P)

Comment: You are welcome, just added some more to my post, so check it out! :)